# How to limit the accessibility among different projects in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

If I have for example three projects like this:

1. WebApi(asp.net web core)
2. Shared.Infrastructure(Contains Generic repo)
3. DAL(Use EF Core)

---

The second project has a reference of the third project.
and the first project(the api) has a reference of the second project.

What I had observed is:

> All things in the third project is accessible in the first project
>   (api) including the `db context and the EF core` !

---

I want the `DAL` to be not accessible expect from the second project. I don't want this transferable dependency between the first and the third project because now any one in the `API` can skip repo in the second project and use the third project (`DAL`) directly!

Comment: Your API is the container, so it has to know about all the classes in order to build the dependency graph. This is basic dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to edit `Shared.Infrastructure.csproj` so that the DAL project is set as a `PrivateAsset`:

```
<ProjectReference Include="path-to-DAL.csproj">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</ProjectReference>
```

See the reference on `PrivateAssets` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets).